# SQL Query For Grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hi i need help with a query

I have a table Where Jobs and Employee are linked its called EmployeeToJobsApplied

```
Id    EmployeeId       JobsId      Applied     Viewed
 1         1             1            True      True
 2         1             2            False     True
 3         1             1            True      True
 4         1             3            True      True
```

If you noticed there are repeating values like in ID=3

I didn't create the database structure. I can't do much about the table structure as of this point since this is a post production project.

The thing i can change is the StoredProcedure that could retrieve information from this table.

So what i need is a single column sigle row value of the Total of Jobs Applied

So basically what i need based on this example is to get a value of

2 Jobs Applied for Employee ID = 1

i want to ignore the duplicates.

Thank You!

Please feel free to edit/retag

**UPDATE**
*I do need the total of the result,
I need the total count (not the list) of Employees who applied for a specific job.
I tried using count and i'ts not working accordingly, Because it counts also those who are not distinct. Thank you for your kind help*

Comment: I don't see any repeats of `ID=3`

Comment: @JonEgerton - He means `ID=3`has values for `EmployeeID` and `JobsID` which are duplicates of `ID=1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to aggregate on distinct values, then you can write:

```
select EmployeeId, count(distinct JobsId) as JobsApplied
from EmployeeToJobsApplied
where Applied = 1
group by EmployeeId
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `distinct`.

```
select distinct * from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

if you dont need id in your result set then, it's simple to use `distinct` something like:

```
SELECT distinct employeeid, JobsId, Applied, Viewed
FROM EmployeeToJobsApplied
```

additionally you can use the where clause to remove results where `Applied` is false:

```
WHERE Applied = true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct EmployeeId, JobsId from EmployeeToJobsApplied
```

since you don't seem to care about the applied and viewed columns

Answer (score 0):

Instead of distinct we can group by our columns

```
select id,JobsId,Applied,Viewed from Emp
group by id,JobsId
```

As distinct hits performance.