# Grouping in classic ASP

Tags: sql-server-2008, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a list of graduates in a mssql table with several years of renewals.  I have been tasked with  listing them by grad id and their renewal years separated by commas instead of one on each line.  Some users have as many as 8 renewals.
They are listed as such:

```
Lisa Jones 123456 2001 CMC
Lisa Jones 123456 2002 CMC
Lisa Jones 123456 2003 CMC
```

ultimately I would like to see:

```
Lisa Jones 123456 2001, 2002, 2003 CMC
```

Is there a way I can do this with a sql query or an asp function??  I have over 2300 records where the Grad ID is unique (123456) but the renewal dates are different.  Grouped by grad id the count would be 275.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Please post any code that you've already written.

Comment: I have not.  I wasn't really sure where to start.  I can also access the table in php.  It's one table called hubspot, if I group it by grad id then by certification type, and omit the renewal years I get 725.  Some grads have multiple certifications.  the sticky wicket is the renewal year.

Comment: Duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358850/sql-query-for-grouping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this one in SQL, myself. Quite easy using the STUFF function in SQL Server 2008+.

I have mocked up an example using a table variable. You would swap the usage of the table variable for your real table named hubspot (replace @hubspot with hubspot).

Example setup (only needed to run the full example):

```
declare @hubspot table
(
    name varchar(100),
    grad_id int,
    renewal_year varchar(10),
    certification_type varchar(10)
)

insert into @hubspot values ('Lisa Jones', 123456, 2001, 'CMC')
insert into @hubspot values ('Lisa Jones', 123456, 2002, 'CMC')
insert into @hubspot values ('Lisa Jones', 123456, 2003, 'CMC')
insert into @hubspot values ('Lisa Jones', 123456, 2004, 'CMC')
```

Use this SQL on your table hubspot:

```
  select name
       , grad_id
       , STUFF((select ', ' + renewal_year
                  from @hubspot b 
                 where b.grad_id = a.grad_id
                 for xml path('')), 1, 2, '') as renewal_years
       , certification_type
    from @hubspot a
group by name
       , grad_id
       , certification_type
```

Output:

[image]

Documentation on STUFF function:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thank you, I will try this now!

Comment: If this worked for you, please consider choosing the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I realized I only had mssql 2005 at work so I'm installing 2008 in my home office today.  I'll work with it then and let you know.  If not, I'll have to use mySQL instead.  Many thanks for your answer, I had actually tried it before I left work Friday but realized it was bombing at the xml path verbiage so I spent some time looking into it.  Thanks again and I'll let you know as soon as possible.  Please accept my apology for the delay.

Comment: mpalmer78, the error I get is "incorrect syntax near 'xml'".

Comment: @meldrape, the STUFF function will only work on MS SQL 2008+. Let me know which server type and version you need assistance for and I'll show you a working alternative.

Comment: I managed to find another client with SQL Server 2017.  This is the error I receive: Error in WHERE clause near '('.
Unable to parse query text.

Comment: Ok, I finally managed to get it to work.  I can't even begin to thank you enough for your help.

Comment: glad to help, @meldrape